# Does LENGTH(trim(:NEW.ADDRESS)) trim the ":NEW.ADDRESS" for the entire script?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, string-length

I am new to oracle and I am trying to write a trigger to a table before inserting the Address. I what to check if there are any spaces '' getting saved to the column.

```
IF LENGTH((:NEW.ADDRESS))=1 and  LENGTH(trim(:NEW.ADDRESS))>LENGTH((:NEW.ADDRESS)) Then 
  --Do Something
END IF;
```

So my question is does trim(:NEW.ADDRESS), trim off the space for the entire Trigger code or does it only trim for the particular part? like if I have to use (:NEW.ADDRESS) somewhere below does it have the original space?

like, let us assume we have

```
 :NEW.ADDRESS='TEMP '
 where LENGTH((:NEW.ADDRESS))=5 
and LENGTH(trim(:NEW.ADDRESS)) =4
```

So if i have to use it after this line of code what would be the value in :NEW.ADDRESS?  'TEMP'(Len 4) or 'TEMP '(Len 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is does trim(:NEW.ADDRESS), trim off the space for the entire Trigger code or does it only trim for the particular part? like if I have to use (:NEW.ADDRESS) somewhere below does it have the original space?

[The `TRIM()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions219.htm#SQLRF06149) does not affect the value passed in. It returns a copy of the value which has been trimmed. You can call it with a literal or the result of an expression, not just a variable, and it would be impossible to modify those.

So if you refer to `:NEW.ADDRESS` again it will still be the same, with any leading or trailing spaces. And the value actually stored in the table will include the spaces.

This would be easy to verify yourself of course.

If you want to modify the value being inserted you need to assign it:

```
:NEW.ADDRESS := trim(:NEW.ADDRESS);
```

If you do that early you won't have to trim it again before checking the length. And the value actually stored in the table not will *not* include the spaces. But you can't then see the original untrimmed value, unless you make a local copy.